# Bash bulk create file

Tags: bash

Folder contains some files:

file.exe, example.exe etc.

The task is to create empty files in the same folder with matching names but different extension:

file.cfg, example.cfg

then delete all .exe files.

How do I do that?

Comment: Does this help? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19654/how-do-i-change-the-extension-of-multiple-files

Answer (score 1):

Find all files with `.exe`, replace file ending. `touch` creates files. `rm` removes files. Inspiration taken from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19654/how-do-i-change-the-extension-of-multiple-files).

```
find *.exe -print -type f | xargs -I {} bash -c 'filename={}; touch ${filename%.exe}.cfg; rm {}'
```

Comment: you don't need to copy the file name touch new one then remove the old, have a look to my answer

Comment: It looks cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: you can empty contents of a file by redirecting the output of `/dev/null`

Comment: That is another option. I find `touch` cleaner :)

Comment: This one fails if name contains brackets ()

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can empty contents of a file by redirecting output of `/dev/null` to it (file) as input using `cat` command:

`cat /dev/null > file.exe`

alternative as per `Mark Setchell` suggestion You can remove the `cat /dev/null` altogether as `>` file will empty it :

`> file.exe`

just to make it easy and clean you have to loop over these files and do the needful for each one of them as below:

```
cd /yourabsolutepath/
for i in *.exe
do
    > "$i" && mv "$i" "${i%%.*}.cfg"
done
```

to remove suffix `.exe` you can use Substitution `${i%%.*}`

Comment: You can remove the `cat /dev/null` altogether as `> file` will empty it.

Comment: @MarkSetchell great, then I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it pretty succinctly with **GNU Parallel**:

```
parallel '> {.}.cfg ; rm {}' ::: *.exe
```

If you want to do a dry-run to see what it would do without actually doing anything:

```
parallel --dry-run '> {.}.cfg ; rm {}' ::: *.exe
```

**Sample Output**

```
> a.cfg ; rm a.exe
> b.cfg ; rm b.exe
> c.cfg ; rm c.exe
```